# how do I turn off logging in java c3p0 connection pooling lib?

Tags: java, c3p0

hey all, I'm just getting started with c3p0 for database connection pooling. It's attaching itself to my log4j output currently. How do I set logging off or at least to SEVERE level only for c3p0? I tried tweaking the properties file but not sure it's being picked up properly.

any ideas on how best to turn it off?

thanks

UPDATE:
this seems to work in the log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl=INFO

log4j.logger.com.mchange=INFO
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use a log4j.xml file you can simple define a logger for the c3po package:

```
<logger name="com.mchange.v2.c3p0">
    <level value="SEVERE"/>
</logger>
```

There are analogous methods for log4j.properties. I think it's just:

```
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0=SEVERE
```

Comment: I'm currently using a log4j.properties file, any idea how to do it in there?

Comment: added a log4j.properties logger example

Comment: thanks! I had to tweak it a little but the log4j.properties file worked :)

Comment: @James how would this looks like in log4j2 properties file?

Comment: How to do this in log4j2.properties?

Answer (score 41):

For those who are NOT using a configuration file, just to add the following in the code, before loading the connection pool.

```
Properties p = new Properties(System.getProperties());
p.put("com.mchange.v2.log.MLog", "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog");
p.put("com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL", "OFF"); // Off or any other level
System.setProperties(p);
```

Comment: `import java.util.Properties;`

Answer (score 4):

I was getting messages like the following:

```
Tue Feb 12 13:42:01 EST 2013 INFO: Profiler Event: [FETCH]  at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76) duration: 0 ms, connection-id: 67, statement-id: 23, resultset-id: 27
```

This made me think that C3P0 was logging these messages. Actually the message is coming from the mysql connector because I enabled profiling by using a connection string like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?profileSQL=true
```

Remove `?profileSQL=true` to make it stop logging these messages.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed problem with line of code:

```
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog.getLogger().setLevel(MLevel.INFO);
```

I am using log4j in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can set log level by adding following lines in log4j.xml
Logging at least at Error level is desired.

```
< category name="com.mchange" additivity="false"> 
        < priority value="ERROR"/>
        < appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
     </ category>
```

If you really want to turn off c3P0 logging set property `com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL=OFF`

in c3p0-Config.properties

or you can directly set this in code as an System property `System.setProperty("com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL",MLevel.OFF);`

Comment: Adding one more additional line in properties file worked for me , `com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog`

Answer (score 1):

I am working on clojure, through korma and for the life of my I could not get any properties files to load (I am new to clojure so I blame myself).  If you are in a similar boat, the following might help you out.

```
(System/setProperties 
  (doto (java.util.Properties. (System/getProperties))
    (.put "com.mchange.v2.log.MLog" "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog")
    (.put "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DEFAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL" "OFF")))
```

The is basically a clojure port of Philippe Carriere's answer above, thank you so much!

Comment: Using Korma I needed to use this code before requiring its namespaces.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that.  If Korma is loaded, then the defaults so the lines above won't overwrite what is already set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring, you can disable c3p0 logging by configuring it in application.properties:

```
logging.level.com.mchange.v2.c3p0=off
```