# c3p0 logging is not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I am not getting c3p0 logging, my **log4j.properties** file is as below:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hb.layout.ConversionPattern=HibernateLog --> %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.hb.Threshold=TRACE

log4j.appender.c3p0=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.c3p0.File=/var/log/fni/c3p0.log
log4j.appender.c3p0.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.c3p0.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.c3p0.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd

# c3p0 logger
log4j.category.com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=info, c3p0
log4j.category.com.mchange.v2.c3p0=info, c3p0
log4j.category.com.mchange.v2.resourcepool=debug, c3p0
```

Below is part of my Spring Config

```
<bean
    id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="configLocation">    
        <value>
            classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop> 
            </props>
     </property>
</bean>    

<bean name="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=sample" />
    <property name="user" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="sa@123" />

</bean>
```

However I am getting hibernate log and I have also c3p0 jar file added, what I am missing? How to know my c3p0 connection pooling is working or not?

Answer (score 9):

agreeing with M Deinum, in my log4j tests of c3p0, i've used logger, not category. i.e.

```
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0=INFO,c3p0
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.resourcepool=DEBUG,c3p0
```

also, you can force c3p0 to log to log4j if for some reason it is logging to some other logging library it has found. in a c3p0.properties file or as a System property to your VM, add

```
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog
```

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using `log4j.logger` instead of `log4j.category`, next to that I would strongly recommend using a log4j.xml file which is (IMHO) more readable then the properties file. Instead of all the separate loggers/categories I would start with the base one `com.mchange` and set it to DEBUG or TRACE.

Another thing your `hibernate.c3p0` properties don't do a thing as you are injecting a datasource.

[how do I turn off logging in java c3p0 connection pooling lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976308/how-do-i-turn-off-logging-in-java-c3p0-connection-pooling-lib) has some related information.

Answer (score 0):

I had made silly mistake, It was already working but I was using `DailyRollingFileAppender` and trying to find log in console, so I replace it with `ConsoleAppender` and it works.